# Mock call super method - protected

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, protected

My problem is that I want to test B class, with mocking super call method, because I don't need to test super.doSomething() there.

```
public class A{
    protected void doSomething(){
        //some Code
    }
}

public class B extends A{
    @Override
    protected void doSomething(){
        //some Code
        super.doSomething();
    }
}
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you even want to do such a thing?

The guarantee it gives you is: *B.doSomething() behaves correctly, **provided that A.doSomething() never changes and provided that A forever remains the superclass of B***.

Is your goal to seal the implementation of `A` and `B`? The goal of unit testing is usually the opposite - to encourage refactoring. In your case:

- if someone modifies `A.doSomething()` in a breaking way, your test will still pass, (**a false positive**)
- if someone extracts just a single line of code from `B.doSomething()` to `A.doSomething()` (which is not that unlikely, given that they are already oriented towards code reuse), the test will most likely fail (a **false negative**)

Answer (score 0):

**This isn't possible.**

Try to *use composition instead of inheritance* to make your tests work.

I mean if possible do something like:

```
public class B extends A{

    //notice the composition of class A into class B

    private A a;
    ........

    @Override
    protected void doSomething(){
        //some Code
        a.doSomething();
    }
    ......
}
```

Here you can easily mock out the `a` in your tests.

If this is not the choice, then you'll have to mock everything inside the `super.doSomething()` method. And **`powermockito`** might come in handy too.